# Como abrir la aplicación de google maps haciendo click en un marcador de un mapa ya insertado en una app usando angular y la librería @amg

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, google-maps

Por ejemplo tengo estos 3 marcadores en mi mapa
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando hago click en alguno de los 3 me muestra cierta información del lugar y un boton

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que cuando toque ese boton abrir la aplicación de google maps con las cordenadas para que me marque la ruta a seguir para llegar hacia allí.

De antemano gracias!!

Comment: Hola, te invito a hacer el [tour] del sitio y a leer [ask] para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida. Por favor comparte el código que tengas para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score 0):

hice algo parecido, en ves de un botón puse un Link y así quedo:

```
<agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" [zoom]="17">
<agm-marker
  [latitude]="lat"
  [longitude]="lng"
  (markerClick)="clickedMarker(infowindow)"
  [iconUrl]=""
>
  <agm-info-window #infowindow>
    <strong class="labelMaker">Categoría: </strong><br />
    <strong class="labelMaker">Nombre: </strong> <br />
    <strong class="labelMaker">Teléfono: </strong><br />
    <a target="_blank"
      jstcache="6"
      href='http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr={{lat}},{{lng}}&daddr={{lat}},{{lng}}'
      tabindex="0">
      <span>Ver en Google Maps ☺</span>
    </a>
  </agm-info-window>
</agm-marker>
```